# MongoDB: How to find a record and aggregate with other fields ( GroupBy and Count)

Tags: mongodb, count, find, aggregate, group

I have a collection that takes users tickets, their status, vehicle, store and city.

```
[
  {
    "ticketNo": "122",
    "active": "false",
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "Vikas",
    "vehicleNo": "ABC123",
    "store": "DT",
    "city": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "141",
    "active": "false",
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "Vikas",
    "vehicleNo": "ABC123",
    "store": "DT",
    "city": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "142",
    "active": "false",
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "Vikas",
    "vehicleNo": "ABC123",
    "store": "DT",
    "city": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "124",
    "active": "false",
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "Vikas",
    "vehicleNo": "ABC124",
    "store": "CityCenter",
    "city": "Gurugram"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "127",
    "active": "false",
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "Vikas",
    "vehicleNo": "ABC124",
    "store": "DT",
    "city": "Nagpur"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "143",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "Vikas",
    "vehicleNo": "ABC124",
    "store": "DT",
    "city": "Nagpur"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "129",
    "active": "false",
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "Vikas",
    "vehicleNo": "ABC125",
    "store": "Ambience",
    "city": "Chennai"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "132",
    "active": "false",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC223",
    "store": "DT",
    "city": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "134",
    "active": "false",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC124",
    "store": "CityCenter",
    "city": "Gurugram"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "144",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC124",
    "store": "CityCenter",
    "city": "Gurugram"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "137",
    "active": "false",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC124",
    "store": "DT",
    "city": "Nagpur"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "139",
    "active": "false",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC121",
    "store": "Ambience",
    "city": "Chennai"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "121",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "Vikas",
    "vehicleNo": "ABC123",
    "store": "Ambience",
    "city": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "147",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC121",
    "store": "Ambience",
    "city": "Chennai"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "123",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "Vikas",
    "vehicleNo": "ABC123",
    "store": "MGF",
    "city": "Mumbai"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "125",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "Vikas",
    "vehicleNo": "ABC123",
    "store": "Ambience",
    "city": "Kolkata"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "126",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "Vikas",
    "vehicleNo": "ABC123",
    "store": "MGF",
    "city": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "128",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "123",
    "name": "Vikas",
    "vehicleNo": "ABC123",
    "store": "CityCenter",
    "city": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "130",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC223",
    "store": "CityCenter",
    "city": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "131",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC223",
    "store": "Ambience",
    "city": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "148",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC223",
    "store": "Ambience",
    "city": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "133",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC223",
    "store": "MGF",
    "city": "Mumbai"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "135",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC123",
    "store": "Ambience",
    "city": "Kolkata"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "136",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC123",
    "store": "MGF",
    "city": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "138",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC123",
    "store": "CityCenter",
    "city": "Delhi"
  },
  {
    "ticketNo": "140",
    "active": "true",
    "userId": "124",
    "name": "Ajay",
    "vehicleNo": "CBC123",
    "store": "CityCenter",
    "city": "Delhi"
  }
]
```

Now I need to find out the total tickets counts of each user, vehicle, store and city using a particular ticketNo.

For eg. ticketNo. 134 is belongs to user Ajay (124). So I need to find out the active & inactive ticket counts of each Ajay's each vehicle in each store of every city.

I can first find details of ticket 134 and then destruct the details (userId, vehicleNo, store, city). Next then I can run the multiple separate aggregate queries to get the relevant count of each one but is that possible with single query like above.

What should be aggregate query for this in MongoDB.

Playground Link of the above data and query is below one.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/tMy8THpkCkT

I am trying to write something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "city": "$city",
        "store": "$store",
        "vehicle": "$vehicleNo",
        "userId": "$userId"
      },
      totalTickets: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      city: "$_id.city",
      store: "$_id.store",
      vehicle: "$_id.vehicle",
      userId: "$_id.userId",
      total: "$totalTickets",
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      total: -1,
    }
  }
])
```

This gives me below results

```
[
  {
    "city": "Delhi",
    "store": "DT",
    "total": 3,
    "userId": "123",
    "vehicle": "ABC123"
  },
  {
    "city": "Chennai",
    "store": "Ambience",
    "total": 2,
    "userId": "124",
    "vehicle": "CBC121"
  },
  {
    "city": "Delhi",
    "store": "CityCenter",
    "total": 2,
    "userId": "124",
    "vehicle": "CBC123"
  },
  {
    "city": "Gurugram",
    "store": "CityCenter",
    "total": 2,
    "userId": "124",
    "vehicle": "CBC124"
  },
  {
    "city": "Nagpur",
    "store": "DT",
    "total": 2,
    "userId": "123",
    "vehicle": "ABC124"
  },
  {
    "city": "Delhi",
    "store": "Ambience",
    "total": 2,
    "userId": "124",
    "vehicle": "CBC223"
  },
  {
    "city": "Gurugram",
    "store": "CityCenter",
    "total": 1,
    "userId": "123",
    "vehicle": "ABC124"
  },
  ....
]
```

I am not able to understand the further grouping and counting of store wise, vehicle wise, user wise and city wise. I can put ticketNo or user or store or vehicle or city in match in the start and rest query remain same to project the required no. count. Something like below.

```
{ $match: { ticketNo: '134'}},
{ $group: {}},
{ $project: {}},

/// overall selective projection for response.
{ $project: {
     cityName: 'cityName',
     cityTicketsCount: 'totalTicketsCountOfAllVehiclesOfAllStoresInThatCity',
     storeTicketsCount: 'totalTicketsCountOfAllVehiclesInThatStore',
     vehicleTicketsCount: 'totalTicketsCountsOfThatVehicle'
  }
}
```

Playground Link of the above data and query is below one.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/tMy8THpkCkT

Expectation:
Every city, store and user has number of open tickets. So I want whenever someone enter the tickets, we get the total number of open tickets of that user, for his every vehicle, in every store, in each city.
Results could be something like:

```
{ ticketNo: 134, status:true, openTicketCountStatus: { vehicles:20, stores: 30, city:100 } }
```

Idea is to tell the summary of x number of tickets open for other vehicles, stores and city.

So think like that, We have 10 city, who has 100 stores, these 100 stores has 500 users who has 400 vehicles and these 400 vehicles has 500 open tickets. So its a hierarchy and data is in different collections with reference ids. Need to just have a summary of open tickets count till city level.

Using this count summary, i can block/unblock further limit of tickets citywise, storewise, userwise and vehiclewise. Think like a city maximun can have 100 tickets, store can have 10 tickets, vehicle can have 4 tickets and user can have 2 tickets max.

Comment: The question is not clear. I see no `ticketNo. 134` here and I don't understand what is the expected result. Please edit the question so we could help

Comment: @nimrodserok - Have updated the questions with full data, truncate data earlier as whole data is there in the link. So I just want to have a summary of counts along with finding status of the ticket.